# An application of strenghtening of the Vopenka's principle

Tags: category-theory, set-theory, ordinals

The well-known Vopěnka prinicple states that for a proper class of models of a first-order
language $L_{\omega\ \omega}$ there exists a nontrivial embedding from one to another model
and it has many applications. Suppose that we strengthen this existence and require that there is
$\lambda$ many elementary embeddings. Are there any applications of this modified VP, or at least
is it consistent with ZFC?

Comment: There are $\lambda$ embedding between what?

Comment: Doesn't VP already gives the existence of many elementary embeddings? Let $\langle \mathcal M_\alpha\mid\alpha\in\mathrm{Ord}\rangle$ be a class of elementary structures of some language and suppose VP holds. Fix $\lambda$ and suppose that there are less than $\lambda$ many $\xi\in\mathrm{Ord}$ such that $\mathcal M_\xi$ elementary embed into some $\mathcal M_\alpha$. Then removing those $\mathcal M_\xi$ will give you a counterexample to VP

Answer (score 2):

For any cardinal $\lambda$ your suggested strengthening is just equivalent to the usual Vopěnka's principle (and so is consistent with ZFC relative to very large cardinals when formulated in one of its first order versions).

For the nontrivial direction suppose that $\mathsf{VP}$ holds, let $\langle \mathcal M_\alpha\mid\alpha\in\mathrm{Ord}\rangle$ be a proper class of structures of some first order language and let $\lambda$ be a fixed cardinal. Suppose for a contradiction that there are less than $\lambda$-many $\xi\in\mathrm{Ord}$ such that $\mathcal M_\xi$ elementary embeds into some $\mathcal M_\alpha$ and let $$A=\{\xi\in\mathrm{Ord}\mid \exists\alpha\in\mathrm{Ord}\; \mathcal M_\xi\prec\mathcal M_\alpha\}.$$
Then $\langle \mathcal M_\alpha\mid\alpha\in\mathrm{Ord}\setminus A\rangle$ is a proper class of structures of the same language no two of which elementary embed into each other, contradicting $\mathsf{VP}$.

Comment: I thought the question was different, namely, whether you can find pairs $\alpha<\beta$ such that there are $\lambda$ elementary embeddings from $\mathcal M_\alpha$ into $\mathcal M_\beta$. Or some variant of this idea: Are there $\alpha$ such that there are $\lambda$ ordinals $\beta$ with an embedding from $M_\alpha$ into $M_\beta$? Or perhaps: Are there $\beta$ such that there are $\lambda$ ordinals $\alpha$ with such an embedding? Or something along these lines, in any case.

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo I see, I hadn't considered that this is also a possible interpretation, I guess we'll need to wait for the OP to clarify. In the meantime is it possible to cook up some "rigid" theory such that between any two models there is at most one elementary embedding? My model theory is very weak, but it sounds possible to me

Comment: What I had in mind is what @AndrésE.Caicedo writes in his first sentence, i.e. that there are $\alpha<\beta$ such that there are $\lambda$ elementary embeddings from $\cal M_{\alpha}$ into $\cal M_{\beta}$. But I think that this is in general inconsistent:suppose that **all** the models' underlying sets are singletons. Then there is in a proper class of them **at most one** elementary embedding. Or am I missing something important ? But VP itself still holds, if the underlying sets are nonequal such as $\{\emptyset\}$ and $\{\{\emptyset\}\}$ then the emebdding is nonidentity.

Comment: I'm not even sure what are the models in the proper class in classical VP supposed to be ?